# Very slow MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

This query takes a ridiculously long time to execute. Duration / Fetch: 89.778 sec / 0.000 sec

Here's the query:

```
SELECT tblcompanyoperat.COPSCountry,
       AVG(tbldshipfees.Dship Total AnnualUSD) / 
                              AVG(tblcopsyearonyear.COPSMinWageUSD) AS Expr1
FROM (SELECT tblcopsyearonyear.Company NAME,
          tblcopsyearonyear.COPSCountry,
          MAX(tblcopsyearonyear.COPSFinYearEnd) AS MaxOfCOPSFinYearEnd
      FROM tblcopsyearonyear
      GROUP BY tblcopsyearonyear.Company NAME,
        tblcopsyearonyear.COPSCountry
      ORDER BY tblcopsyearonyear.COPSCountry,
        MAX(tblcopsyearonyear.COPSFinYearEnd)) AS qryCOPSLatestInfoYr,
     ((tblcompany 
       INNER JOIN tblcompanyoperat 
       ON tblcompany.CompName = tblcompanyoperat.Company NAME) 
      INNER JOIN tblcopsyearonyear 
      ON tblcompanyoperat.COMPOPID = tblcopsyearonyear.COMPOPID)
INNER JOIN (tbldirectorships 
            INNER JOIN tbldshipfees 
            ON tbldirectorships.DIRECTORSHIPSID = bldshipfees.DSHIPID) 
ON tblcompany.CompName = tbldirectorships.DSHIPCOMPANYLINK
WHERE blcompany.CompSector = 'Retail'
GROUP BY tblcompany.CompSector, 
         blcompanyoperat.COPSCountry,
         tbldshipfees.DSHIP Position
HAVING (AVG(tblcopsyearonyear.COPSMinWageUSD) IS NOT NULL
        AND tbldshipfees.DSHIP Position LIKE 'Chief%')
ORDER BY MAX(qryCOPSLatestInfoYr.MaxOfCOPSFinYearEnd);
```

What optimizations, apart from indexing, can I use to speed things up?
Explain extended output:

```
id selet_type   table                 type possible_keys                                          key                         key_len  ref                                       rows filtered Extra
1, PRIMARY,     tblcompany,           ref, PRIMARY,tblSECTORStblCOMPANY,                          tblSECTORStblCOMPANY,       768,     const,                                    7,   100.00,  Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1, PRIMARY,     tblcompanyoperat,     ref, PRIMARY,CompanyName,                                   CompanyName,                768,     lrsmnc.tblcompany.CompName,               3,   100.00,  Using where
1, PRIMARY,     tblcopsyearonyear,    ref, PRIMARY,COMPOPID,                                      COMPOPID,                   4,       lrsmnc.tblcompanyoperat.COMPOPID,         1,   100.00, 
1, PRIMARY,     tbldirectorships,     ref, PRIMARY,DIRECTORSHIPSID,tblCOMPANYtblDIRECTORSHIPS,    tblCOMPANYtblDIRECTORSHIPS, 768,     lrsmnc.tblcompanyoperat.Company Name,     12,  100.00,  Using where; Using index
1, PRIMARY,     tbldshipfees,         ref, DSHIPID,tbldshipfeesDSHIPID,                           DSHIPID,                    4,       lrsmnc.tbldirectorships.DIRECTORSHIPSID,  1,   100.00, 
1, PRIMARY,     <derived2>,           ALL,                                                                                                                                       310, 100.00,  Using join buffer
2, DERIVED,     tblcopsyearonyear,    ALL,                                                                                                                                       523, 100.00,  Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Comment: Perhaps format your code to make it easier to follow?

Comment: Thanks Alfabravo for the formatting

Comment: Why do you specify "apart from indexing"?

Comment: I don't see anything in the EXPLAIN referencing `tbldshipfees.DSHIP Position`, which you're using in a `LIKE` constraint?  In general, I wouldn't restrict people trying to help you, they'll restrict themselves if you provide the necessary information...

Comment: Not going to help with performance, but you shouldn't prefix/suffix tables (columns, views, etc) with type information (eg. `'tbl...'`).  If everything is prefixed it's noise.  If it's datatype, you may be in trouble if it ends up changing for some reason.

Comment: The database has an index on `tbldshipfees.DSHIP Position`. I don't know if it is used or not, and if not why.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem with that then.  From MySQL documentation, the `HAVING` clause is applied last, with no optimization.  Since it looks like you could pop that up into the `WHERE` clause instead of `HAVING` (doesn't reference an aggregate column that I see...), you could get a performance boost that way?  (ref http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

Comment: The `ORDER BY` inside your subselect is useless, removing it would (probably) help.  Also, the mixing of the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause) with all the regular joins, plus the way you've got them nested in parenthesis, isn't really helping any.  We may need to see the schema definitions, and potentially some sample data, to better figure out what can be dealt with.  I have my suspicions about the `MAX()` function in the outer `ORDER BY` statement.

Comment: Moving `tbldshipfees.DSHIP Position LIKE 'Chief%'` to the where clause brought execution down to 7.348 seconds. I am happy with that.

Comment: @X-Zero I suspect that the mixing of the implicit-join syntax with all the regular joins is the real problem, since I have a similar query with only regular joins which runs quick. How to fix?

Comment: The optimizer is probably turning it into `INNER JOIN`s already (or vice versa, can't remember what mySQL does).  It's just a huge headache for future maintainers.  You can _probably_ change them to `INNER JOIN`s - you're missing the _actual_ correlation condition to tie them together (you may be getting extra rows), but `AVG()` (in the `HAVING` clause) would only return `NULL` if there were 0 rows in that result, so it's _some_ sort of `INNER` join.  If you can figure out the correlation, you could completely remove the `HAVING` clause, which would help.  Provide schema/data for better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving `tbldshipfees.DSHIP Position LIKE 'Chief%'` from the `HAVING` clause to the `WHERE` clause will improve execution time.  This is for two reasons.

First, no optimizations are done to items appearing in the `HAVING` clause for MySQL.  This means that items may not be excluded using the index (as indicated in the `EXPLAIN` plan above.

Second, since the `HAVING` clause is applied immediately before returning the data to the client.  As a result, time is spent unnecessarily in all of the operations (aggregate functions, ORDER BYs, etc) before they are removed, increasing the amount of time taken to process.

Reference:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Additionally, for future maintenance reasons, changing from implicit joins to explicit joins would be recommended, as per X-Zero's comments.  This could have additional performance benefits, as it reduces the optimization required by the database server.

Comment: @X-Zero After changing from an implicit join to an explicit join using `ON qryCOPSLatestInfoYr.COPSCountry = tblcopsyearonyear.COPSCountry` as the correlation condition, I brought execution time down from 7.348 seconds to 0.905 seconds.